# Sikuli Java - How can I sendKeys with accent mark (á, é, í, ó, ú)

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli

This is my code:

```
public class Cls_ObjPrint {
    public void escribirGUI(String valor){
            Keyboard kb = new DesktopKeyboard();
            String input = StringUtils.stripAccents(valor);
            kb.type(input);
        }
}
```

Mi run class

```
    public class Cls_CrearCliente {
    public static void main(Cls_Enco_Elem_Siebel Obj_Enco_Elem_Siebel)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Cls_ObjPrint Obj_Auxiliar= new Cls_ObjPrint();

    Obj_Auxiliar.escribirGUI("Andrés");
    }
    }
```

The output of this part of code is: Andres without the tick
I need send the text with accent mark

Comment: I don't know what `StringUtils.stripAccents()` does but it sounds like it's removing the accents that you are trying to keep.

Comment: @JeffC, I removed the stripaccents() but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of keyDown and NUM Lock keys to type in letters with accents. For eg.

`keyDown(Key.ALT)
 type(Key.NUM0+Key.NUM2+Key.NUM2+Key.NUM5)
 keyUp(Key.ALT)`

For more info -> https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/codealt/#using

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very old, when appear 
special character y do it:

```
        bot.keyPress(VK_DEAD_ACUTE);
        bot.keyPress(VK_A);
        bot.keyRelease(VK_DEAD_ACUTE);
        bot.keyRelease(VK_A);
```

that type : á